# Not able to download all files from a directory using node ssh2

Tags: node.js, sftp

I was trying to download few files using ssh2 package in node. I'm presently using

```
sftp.fastGet(remote_PATH, local_PATH, {}, function(downloadError){
    if(downloadError) throw downloadError;
      console.log("Succesfully downloaded");
    });
```

But not able to download all the files present in the directory. Is it possible using this module? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you have full ssh access, one simple solution is to just stream a tar archive. For example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// ...

ssh.exec('tar czf - /path/to/transfer', function(err, stream) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var localproc = spawn('tar', ['-C', '/path/to/extract/to', 'xf', '-']);
  stream.pipe(localproc);
  stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
    console.log('Tar finished with code %j, signal %j', code, signal);
    // Close connection or do whatever else ...
  });
  // Ignore stderr
  stream.stderr.resume();
});
```